# Upload image files to AWS-S3: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transfer-encoding')

Tags: amazon-s3, mern, multer-s3

I am trying to upload images to AWS-S3 with MERN Stack, but I can't even get the backend to work. I am diligently following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9-3ZLvhL9Q&t=1228s) but I am getting a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transfer-encoding').

I added `encType='multipart/form-data'` to my form in react as suggested by some sites, but it did not work.

I also did the relevant logs with `debug` here and `formData.entries()` produced the names of my files accurately:

```
const onImageChange = (event) => {
    const selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    setFiles(selectedFiles);
    log("event.target.files %o", event.target.files);
    log("selectedFiles %o", selectedFiles);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (files.length === 0) {
      return alert("please select an image");
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    log("formData %o", formData);

    for (const file of files) {
      formData.append("s3Images", file);
    }

    log("formData after append %o", formData);

    for (const entry of formData.entries()) {
      const [key, value] = entry;
      console.log(`${key}:`, value);
    }

    const result = await fetch(BASE_URL + "/upload", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });
    log("result %o", result);

    const data = await result.json();
    log("data %o", data);
```

Is there anything wrong with my multer?

```
const uploadWithMulter = () =>
  multer({
    storage: multerS3({
      s3: s3,
      bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, { fieldname: file.fieldname });
      },
      key: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
      },
    }),
  }).array("s3Images", 2);

const uploadToAws = (req, res) => {
  const upload = uploadWithMulter();

  upload((req, res, error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json({ error, msg: "Error occurred while uploading images." });
      return;
    }
    res.json({ msg: "Files uploaded successfully.", files: req.files });
  });
};

router.post("/upload", uploadToAws);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is way you're handling the upload middleware with Multer. In your uploadWithMulter function, you are calling multer() each time it is called.
Try this

```
const uploadWithMulter = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, { fieldname: file.fieldname });
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
  }),
}).array("s3Images", 2);
```

noww you create the multer middleware only once and then using it in the uploadToAws function. The uploadWithMulter function now returns the configured multer middleware.

(make sure you have the required dependencies)

Comment: Thank you, i see what you are saying, and I have modified it, but that unfortunately didn't work :'( Am not sure what I can be missing at this point.

All my dependencies are installed:

const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const router = express.Router();
const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

require("dotenv").config();

const BUCKET_NAME = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
const REGION = process.env.REGION;
const ACCESS_KEY = process.env.ACCESS_KEY;
const SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

Answer (score 0):

The placement of my bracket caused the issue. It should been upload(req, res, (error) => {if (error) {...}} instead of upload((req, res, error) => {if (error) {...}} that I had originally.

This works:

```js
const uploadToAws = (req, res) => {
  const upload = uploadWithMulter();
  // log("req %o", req);
  upload(req, res, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json({ error, msg: "Error occurred while uploading images." });
      return;
    }
    res.json({ msg: "Files uploaded successfully.", files: req.files });
  });
};
```